# Laravel how to auto get array id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, laravel

I know the title isn't that understanding but I will try to explain here my problem.
So I have a form that auto generates input fields by jquery and I'm trying to store that data in the db

**the blade**:

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="myproduct[]"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Șansa" name="mychance[]"/>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
```

**My Controller**:

```php
class SomeController extends BaseController {
    public function someMethod(Request $request)  {
        ...

        $items = '{"'.$request->myproduct[0].'":"'.$request->mychance[0].'", "'.$request->myproduct[1].'":"'.$request->mychance[1].'"}';

        $case = Cases::create([
            'items' => $items
        ]);
        $case->save();

        ...
    }
}
```

It is kinda working but I want to know how to get all data in $items without creating new variables like $variable[0], $variable[1],2 ,3 for every input I generate

Comment: What you actually want to do

Comment: You get all inputs as array by `$request->input('myproduct')`;

Comment: Yes but when I try to store it it won't work as an array I get this error 'Array to string conversion'

Comment: You want to store all incoming records?

Comment: Yes I want to store all them by this format {"$request->myproduct":"$request->mychance"}

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to do this:

```php
class SomeController extends BaseController {
    public function someMethod(Request $request)  {
        ...
        $items = [];

        foreach($request->myproduct as $i => $myProductSingle) {
            $items[$myProductSingle] = $request->mychance[$i];
        }

        $case = Cases::create([
            'items' => json_encode($items)
        ]);

        $case->save();

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that you always have the same amount of products and choices you can use `array_combine`

```
$myproduct = [1,2,3];
$mychance = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

$items = array_combine($myproduct, $mychance);
// result: [1 => "test1", 2 => "test2", 3 => "test3"]


// encode it to a string with json_encode
// result: "{"1":"test1","2":"test2","3":"test3"}"
$case = Cases::create(['items' => json_encode($items)]);
```

Additionaly you can cast your items column to an `array`

In your Cases model add

```
protected $casts = [
    'items' => 'array',
];
```

Laravel will then automatically serialize it when storing and deserialize it when accessing giving you an array.

then you could just do

```
$myproduct = [1,2,3];
$mychance = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

$case = Cases::create(['items' => array_combine($myproduct, $mychance)]);
```

[Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns
>   that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has
>   a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the
>   array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the
>   attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model

Comment: `array_combine` is indeed shorter answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps..

```
  $items = [];

    foreach($request->myproduct as $key => $myProduct) {
        $items[$myProduct] = $request->mychance[$key];
    }
```